# Restar dos valores de una misma columna en un dataframe de Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

A partir de este DataFrame con nombre *df*

| Sample | Target | Ct | Ct Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C41 | B2M | 20.642399 | 20.680149 |
| C41 | B2M | 20.717901 | 20.680149 |
| C42 | ULK1 | 29.097883 | 29.110802 |
| C42 | ULK1 | 29.123722 | 29.110802 |
| C43 | TBP | 22.126412 | 21,4221565 |
| C43 | TBP | 20.717901 | 21,4221565 |

La columna *Ct Mean* es la media de los dos valores de la columna Ct de la misma *Sample* y *Target* (esto te lo da por defecto el .xlsx que importo al pandas).

Mi intención es comprobar si la diferencia entre los dos valores de la columna *Ct* para la misma muestra y target no es mayor a +-1 dos a dos. Por ejemplo,  para C41 (B2M) la diferencia entre 20.642399 y    20.717901 es menor a 1 con lo cual debería devolver el valor de *Ct* tal cual. En cambio, para C43 (TBP) la diferencia entre 22.126412 y 20.717901 es mayor 1 y sustituir los dos valores de Ct para C43 por "Undetermined". El resultado que debería darme sería este:

| Sample | Target | Ct | Ct Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C41 | B2M | 20.642399 | 20.680149 |
| C41 | B2M | 20.717901 | 20.680149 |
| C42 | ULK1 | 29.097883 | 29.110802 |
| C42 | ULK1 | 29.123722 | 29.110802 |
| C43 | TBP | Undetermined | Undetermined |
| C43 | TBP | Undetermined | Undetermined |

He intentado de varias formas realizar una resta entre dos elementos de una misma columna de un dataframe pero no he sido capaz. La primera era aplicar un bucle para esa columna que hiciese la diferencia entre los dos valores haciendo un salto para que luego haga los dos siguientes:

```
def loop(i):
    for i in range(0,96,2):
        if i-(i+1)>1 or i-(i+1)<(-1):
                i=="Undetermined"
        else:
            return i
prueba = df["Ct"].apply(loop)
prueba
```

Imprime:

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
     ..
91    0
92    0
93    0
94    0
95    0
Name: Ct, Length: 96, dtype: int64
```

NOTA* Mi dataframe tiene 96 filas. Solo he puesto un head con las 6 primeras para el ejemplo.
Al imprimir me da todo 0. He estado buscando y vi que existe el método [`.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html?highlight=diff#pandas.DataFrame.diff) que permite restar el valor de un elemento menos el valor del elemento anterior, pero no sé como aplicarlo. Otra manera que pensé es utilizar:

```
df["Ct"].sub(df[0,len(df),2], axis=0)
```

Obviamente da error y tampoco está bien la sintaxis.

Comment: Sólo por confirmar... si lo he entendido bien el C42 debería ser también Undetermined, no?

Comment: Perdona. Copie mal el dato. Ya esta editado correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar diff pero luego tendrías que recuperar los segundos elementos de cada grupo para ver la diferencia y sustituir los valores de cada uno de ellos. Quizá conceptualmente es un poco más de lío, así que primero te propongo una alternativa y luego te explico cómo hacerlo con `diff`.

**Opción 1: Group by**

Lo que buscas es agrupar por la columna muestra, calcular la diferencia y devolver una máscara en la que se indique si la diferencia es mayor que 1 o no. Con esa máscara modificarías los valores de tu dataframe en aquellos en los que se cumpla la condición:

```
# creamos la función de comparación
def check_diff(series):
    values = series.tolist()
    return abs(values[0] - values[1]) > 1

# agrupamos utilizando como key la columna Sample y nuestra función de agregación
df_check = df[['Sample', 'Ct']].groupby('Sample').agg({'Ct': check_diff})

# Combinamos los dos dataframes
df = pd.merge(df, df_check, how='left', on='Sample')
```

Llegados a este punto tienes este dataframe

| Sample | Target | Ct_x | Ct Mean | Ct_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C41 | B2M | 20.6424 | 20.6801 | False |
| C41 | B2M | 20.7179 | 20.6801 | False |
| C42 | ULK1 | 29.0979 | 29.1108 | False |
| C42 | ULK1 | 29.1237 | 29.1108 | False |
| C43 | TBP | 22.1264 | 21.4222 | True |
| C43 | TBP | 20.7179 | 21.4222 | True |

La columna *Ct_y* nos indica si la diferencia es mayor que 1, por lo que ya podríamos reemplazar los valores

```
# Por ejemplo puedes hacer algo así (recuerda importar numpy)
df['Ct'] = np.where(df['Ct_y'] == True, 'Undetermined', df['Ct_x'])
df['Ct Mean'] = np.where(df['Ct_y'] == True, 'Undetermined', df['Ct Mean'])

df.drop(columns=['Ct_x', 'Ct_y'], inplace=True)
```

Nuestro dataframe quedaría tal que así:

| Sample | Target | Ct Mean | Ct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C41 | B2M | 20.680149 | 20.642399 |
| C41 | B2M | 20.680149 | 20.717901 |
| C42 | ULK1 | 29.110802 | 29.097883 |
| C42 | ULK1 | 29.110802 | 29.123722 |
| C43 | TBP | Undetermined | Undetermined |
| C43 | TBP | Undetermined | Undetermined |

Realmente podrías simplificarlo sin pasar por la columna con True y False y devolviendo directamente la diferencia, con lo que sería algo así:

```
def get_diff(series):
    values = series.tolist()
    return abs(values[0] - values[1])


df_check = df[['Sample', 'Ct']].groupby('Sample').agg({'Ct': get_diff})

df = pd.merge(df, df_check, how='left', on='Sample')

df['Ct'] = np.where(df['Ct_y'] > 1, 'Undetermined', df['Ct_x'])
df['Ct Mean'] = np.where(df['Ct_y'] > 1, 'Undetermined', df['Ct Mean'])
df.drop(columns=['Ct_x', 'Ct_y'], inplace=True)
```

---

**Opción 2: Diff**
Primero calculamos diff (asumiendo que esté el dataframe ordenado) y eliminamos los duplicados para quedarnos con el último elemento:

```
df['Diff'] = df['Ct'].diff()

df_check = df.drop_duplicates('Sample', keep='last')
df_check = df_check[['Sample', 'Diff']]
```

| Sample | Diff |
| --- | --- |
| C41 | 0.075502 |
| C42 | 0.025839 |
| C43 | -1.40851 |

Con este dataframe ya podemos operar exactamente igual que en la opción 1

```
df = pd.merge(df, df_check, how='left', on='Sample')

df['Ct'] = np.where(df['Ct_y'] > 1, 'Undetermined', df['Ct_x'])
df['Ct Mean'] = np.where(df['Ct_y'] > 1, 'Undetermined', df['Ct Mean'])
df.drop(columns=['Ct_x', 'Ct_y'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solución

```
def myfunc(g):
  if any(g.Ct.diff().abs()>1):
    g["Ct Mean"] = "Undetermined"
    g["Ct"] = "Undetermined"
  return g

df = df.groupby(["Sample", "Target"]).apply(myfunc)
```

### Demo

Si `df` inicialmente contiene:

```
  Sample Target         Ct     Ct Mean
0    C41    B2M  20.642399   20.680149
1    C41    B2M  20.717901   20.680149
2    C42   ULK1  29.097883   29.110802
3    C42   ULK1  29.123722   29.110802
4    C43    TBP  22.126412  21,4221565
5    C43    TBP  20.717901  21,4221565
```

el resultado del código anterior produce:

```
  Sample Target            Ct       Ct Mean
0    C41    B2M     20.642399     20.680149
1    C41    B2M     20.717901     20.680149
2    C42   ULK1     29.097883     29.110802
3    C42   ULK1     29.123722     29.110802
4    C43    TBP  Undetermined  Undetermined
5    C43    TBP  Undetermined  Undetermined
```

### Cómo funciona

Como ves todo se resuelve en una línea:

```
df.groupby(["Sample", "Target"]).apply(myfunc)
```

Lo que hace esto es agrupar el dataframe por "Sample" y "Target" de modo que reúne en varios "sub-dataframes" las filas que tengan el mismo valor en "Sample" y "Target". A cada uno de los "sub-dataframes" resultantes (que llamaremos en adelante "grupos") se les aplica la función `myfunc`.

Esta función recibe por tanto en su parámetro `g` un grupo, que es en realidad un dataframe pero "filtrado" de modo que tiene solo un par de elementos con el mismo Sample y Target, al menos en este caso son solo un par de elementos. De forma más general reciben un dataframe con un número arbitrario de filas, con las mismas columnas que el `df` original, y con el mismo valor de "Sample" y "Target" en todas las filas.

Lo que hace la función es determinar si en ese grupo hay que cambiar el valor de la columna "Ct Mean" para ponerle "Undetermined" o hay que dejarlo como estaba. Después retorna el grupo en cuestión, para que `.apply()` lo vaya concatenando de nuevo con los restantes grupos para crear el dataframe con el resultado.

La clave para determinar si hay que poner o no "Undetermined" es la línea siguiente:

```
  if any(g.Ct.diff().abs()>1):
```

`g.Ct` es la columna Ct del grupo recibido. Al aplicarle `.diff()` se resta en esa columna a cada elemento el anterior. El primero no tiene anterior por lo que el resultado sale NaN, pero en los siguientes el resultado será la diferencia. Se tiene así una columna de diferencias. A esa columna se le aplica `.abs()` para quedarse con el valor absoluto de modo que el signo no influya. Se tiene por tanto una columna de números (el primero de ellos NaN).

Se compara la columna con `>1` lo que nos da una nueva columna pero esta vez de booleanos. Para cada elemento de la diferencia que sea mayor de 1, habrá un `True` (y el resto serán `False`). El primero que es `NaN` dará `False` siempre. En tu caso sólo habrá un elemento más (porque sólo hay dos filas en cada grupo), pero de forma general podríamos tener una columna con muchos booleanos.

Esa columna se le pasa a `any()` que devuelve `True` si hay al menos un `True` entre los elementos. Sólo si todos son `False` devolverá  `False`.

El resultado es que si entre los valores retornados por .diff() hay alguno mayor de 1, el `if` se ejecutará y entonces hará:

```
g["Ct Mean"] = "Undetermined"
g["Ct"] = "Undetermined"
```

que asigna ese valor a la columna completa, es decir, a todas las filas de ese grupo. Si el `if` no se cumple, `g` no se toca.

Finalmente la función retorna `g` (haya sido modificado o no).