# Restar fila anterior con numpy de manera simplificada

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Despues de toparme con la pregunta [Restar dos valores de una misma columna en un dataframe de Pandas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/512701/restar-dos-valores-de-una-misma-columna-en-un-dataframe-de-pandas/512716#512716) me preguntaba: ¿Existe alguna funcion en numpy equivalente a la funcion `diff` de pandas, o una manera *elegante* y generalizada de restar la cantidad de filas anteriores que se deseé con numpy? He diseñado una manera de restar la fila anterior pero no esta generalizada y siento que no es nada *elegante*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
array = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3))    
restar= array[:-1]-array[1:])
print(array)
print(restar)
```

---

```
[[2 1 6]
 [4 7 6]
 [3 1 3]]

[[-2 -6  0]
 [ 1  6  3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

En `numpy` también existe `diff`, pero de hecho tu implementación no funciona igual al de `pandas` ni `numpy`, lo que tu estás haciendo es restar la fila siguiente y tanto en `pandas` como en `numpy` se resta la fila anterior.

```
import numpy as np
 
array = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3))
print(array)
out = np.diff(array, axis= 0)
print(out)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
# array
[[8 3 1]
 [9 3 3]
 [6 5 6]]

#out
[[ 1  0  2]
 [-3  2  3]]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! desconocia que existia `diff`

Comment: Una consulta de 2 segundos a Google y devuelve [numpy.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) jaja. Saludos

Comment: JAjaja que raro que a mi no me aparecia! jajaja o no supe buscar bien

Comment: Solo busqué "numpy diff"